# CORS chrome issue when trying to use PHP Exception in AJAX error callback

Tags: php, ajax, google-chrome, exception, cors

When throwing an exception in PHP backend - AJAX error callback launches as needed but err.data is null (and there is CORS error in chrome console) so I can`t implement any custom logic there.

```
auth.oauthLogin(data).then((userData) => {
        // success
    }, (err) => {
        // failure
        if (err.data && err.status === 400) {
        // failure state A
        }
        else
        // failure state B
});
```

I use Silex framework which of course adds Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to normal response, and surely I can manually add this header to Exception, but I am interested what is the right appoach to properly use Exceptions on client side and insert some info into err.someProperty object?

Comment: The Fetch API (which specifies all behavior around how browsers manage requests and responses) doesn’t define receiving a 400 response as a fetch error. Instead it just defines a 400 as a response received without any failure in the fetching behavior from the perspective of the client side — just like any other response — but it’s just not a success/OK response. If you want to check if a response was a success/OK response, you can use `response.ok` https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-response-ok to do that.

Comment: Otherwise, if you want to add specific client-side handling for particular 4xx and 5xx and 3xx responses, then the right way it to pretty much do what you describe in the question, which is: Ensure that the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header gets added to all 4xx and 5xx and 3xx responses — and not just to 2xx responses — and use response.status https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-response-status to get to the exact status code on the client side so you can have your client code handle each case you want to handle specially.